# Replacing list elements using other list

Tags: r

I'm working with two lists in R and am trying to replace elements of one list with those of another.  However, each list's replacement is indexed by a third list.  Consider

```
> template
$X1
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$X2
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$X3
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$X4
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

...

$X35
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and

```
> replace_table
$X1
[1] 5 6 7

$X2
[1] 4 6 7

$X3
[1] 4 5 7

$X4
[1] 4 5 6

...

$X35
[1] 1 2 3
```

Say also that I have the list

```
> set
[1] 3 5 1
```

So the idea here is to loop through template and replace elements in each list of template with replace_list.  So template would end up looking like this

```
> template
$X1
[1] 0 0 0 0 3 5 1

$X2
[1] 0 0 0 3 0 5 1

$X3
[1] 0 0 0 3 5 0 1

$X4
[1] 0 0 0 3 5 1 0

...

$X35
[1] 3 5 1 0 0 0 0
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?  I've tried using

```
lapply(c(1:length(template)), function(x) template[[x]][c(replace_list[[x]])]=c(set))
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have also recommended `Map`, but the following is probably closer to what you had in mind:

```
lapply(seq_along(template), function(x) {
  replace(template[[x]], replace_table[[x]], replace_list)
})
```

Comment: This is the one I went with as I am always trying to use lapply.  I'm not sure I understand seq_along though?

Comment: @rdevn00b, that's just like your `1:length(template)`.

Comment: Ok I see.  So why do I need lapply(foo, function(x) {}) instead of lapply(foo, function(x) replace(x)....)?

Comment: @rdevn00b, Sorry. Don't quite understand your question. Are you asking why there are the curly brackets? If so, just preference in case I wanted to do more operations inside of the `lapply`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Map`. Based on the data showed, 'replace_list' looked more like a `vector`.  `Map` is a wrapper for `mapply` (which is a multivariate version of `sapply`) with `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.  It works by doing the operation on corresponding elements of the lists ('template', 'replace_table').  As we convert 'replace_list' to a `list`, it gets recycled to the length of other two lists.

```
 Map(`[<-`, template, replace_table, list(replace_list))
 #$X1
 #[1] 0 0 0 0 3 5 1

 #$X2
 #[1] 0 0 0 3 0 5 1

 #$X3
 #[1] 0 0 0 3 5 0 1

 #$X4
 #[1] 0 0 0 3 5 1 0
```

The `[<-` is assigning the 'template' list elements using the 'replace_table' elements as index to 'replace_list' vector.

If I use anonymous function, it would be

```
 Map(function(x,y,z) {x[y] <- z;x}, template, replace_table, list(replace_list))
```

#### data

```
template <- setNames(lapply(1:4, function(i) rep(0,7)), paste0('X',1:4))

replace_table <- setNames(list(5:7, c(4,6,7), c(4,5,7), 4:6), names(template))
replace_list <- c(3,5,1)
```

Comment: Interesting, but does map have the speed of lapply?

Comment: @rdevn00b Based on some benchmarks I did for another post, both were of the same speed